# stack 0805 sized component on 1206 sized footprint

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, pcb-assembly

I wonder if it's generally okay to stack an  0805 sized footprint over a 1206 footprint, without any problems in the assembly machine?

Comment: Most of the time, they will usually fit ok. But be prepared to face alot of dry joints if this is going to be mass produced

Comment: What do you mean "stack"? Are you thinking having two footprints and then being able to choose which size to assemble? Or actually stacking an 0805 component on top of a 1206?

Comment: @TomCarpenter choose which size of course!

Comment: @MCG and that can't be avoided with proper care in the assembly line?

Comment: Of course it can be avoided with care.... but you get dry joints etc on standard components on the correct footprint so the chances of it happening to a component going on a larger footprint is obviously higher. It doesn't happen often, but depends on volume

Comment: @MCG It's a pretty small volume 15-70 units a year, the assembly we are hiring says "it's okey". Do you think I should worry or not?

Comment: Give it a go and see how they do. Worst that can happen is you'll have to resolder it due to a dry joint. With low volumes like that I probably wouldn't worry too much

Comment: If components are soldered by reflow and they are not placed in their proper footprint, they usually get moved from they were placed and a correct soldering cannot be guaranteed.